# Using .NET dependencies with Iron.io IronWorker

Tags: c#, .net, iron.io, ironworker

I'm brand new to Iron.io's IronWorker, and I'm attempting to interface with it via C#.NET. I have managed to get [the sample on the site](http://dev.iron.io/worker/languages/dotnet/) to work, which utilizes the System.Web.Script.Serialization library. However, I want to use Newtonsoft.Json library for serialization/deserialization. My `.worker` file (located in the `\bin` directory of a Visual Studio project) looks like this:

```
runtime 'mono'
exec 'Debug\hello.exe'
file 'Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

I'm fairly certain that Newtonsoft.Json is being loaded, because adding the 3rd line of `file: 'Debug\Netwonsoft.Json.dll'` fixed the error that said that Newtonsoft could not be found.

The error I'm receiving when attempting to run a task is the following (I removed any seemingly sensitive information):

```
{"code_id":"[CODE_ID]","code_name":"hello","created_at":"2014-11-
16T13:48:01Z","duration":2452,"end_time":"2014-11-16T13:48:06Z","id":"[ID]","msg":"Unhandled 
Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly
'Newtonsoft.Json'.\n  at HelloWorld.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0 \n[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could
not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly
'Newtonsoft.Json'.\n","project_id":"[PROJECTID]","start_time":
"2014-11-16T13:48:04Z","timeout":3600,"updated_at":"2014-11-16T13:48:07Z","status"
:"error"}
```

In the course of tracking down the error: `Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'`, I ran across a [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933643/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as) that suggested there might be a .NET framework mismatch between v4.0 and v4.5. I'm using v4.5, and I tried changing it to v4.0 with no luck (so this may not be the issue).

**Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how to properly utilize a dependency, such as `Newtonsoft.Json` (so at least the sample on Iron.io will work)?**

*P.S. I've been toying with [IronSharp](http://grcodemonkey.github.io/iron_sharp/) as an API to assist with interfacing with Iron.io products (once I get past this dependency issue). But, I'm open to suggestions if there's anything better I should be checking out.*

**SOLUTION**

@Featalion's answer below really helped, becuase he pointed me to the `stack` command, which I placed in like so:

```
runtime 'mono'
stack 'mono-3.6'
exec 'Debug\hello.exe'
file 'Debug\Netwonsoft.Json.dll'
```

I believe it resolved the error at hand, because the higher mono framework seems to handle the latest version of Newtwonsoft.Json.dll. I'll post here if I find otherwise.

*Make note that as of 11/17/2014, it seems the highest stack version supported by IronWorker is 3.6 (even though 3.10 is available, details [found here](http://www.mono-project.com/)). Check the highest stable release from Iron.io [at this link](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/environment/).*

Comment: I dont know about this framework but shouldn't you define files before starting the process

Comment: @Eric, As far as I know, the `file: 'Debug\Netwonsoft.Json.dll'` is defining the file. Netwtonsoft.Json.dll is also included as a reference inside Visual Studio. Or, perhaps I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, possibly, related to mono version on the IronWorker service. I found [related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542029/json-net-doesnt-work-with-mono-under-debian). Try to change the stack in your `.worker` file to `mono-3.6` or `mono-3.0`. See all possible runtime environments [on Iron.io's dev site](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/environment/#default_language_versions). `mono` runtime is default, and it is alias for `mono-2.10`.

Comment: I selected your answer because your pointing me to the `stack` option was a huge help (so far, I think it fixed my problem). The .NET sample at http://dev.iron.io/worker/languages/dotnet/ only has `runtime`, `exec` and `file`. Thanks a million!